# QGIS - Legend Columns - Uneven distribution of legend items

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I'm working on a legend in QGIS 3.2 but cannot figure out how to get a set of legend items to distribute across 3 columns, but with an uneven number of rows.

For example I have 9 items that display in the legend, when I set the column count to 2, it creates a column with 5 items and a column with 4, however when I set the column count to 3 it give me 3 even columns with three items each.

Due to the layout of my map I want the items to display in 3 columns, but with 4 rows of items in the first 2 columns, and a lone item in the 3rd column.

Can anyone advise me on how to obtain this?

Current Outcome

[image]

Desired Outcome
[image]

Comment: I'm not using version 3, but if I want to achieve this in 2.14 I create 3 copies of the last layer in the legend and set their symbology to white and set the layer name to blank - not elegant but it gets the job done!